# First item in each category list is not a link

Tags: plugin-list-category-post

After the last update of the plugin "List Category Posts" the first post item under each category is just text, no link. This request is made at the request of the plugin author as per the help file associated with the plugin as the means to get answers from HIM.

See example here: http://oneangrycitizen.me/categories/

So the category links work but the post links are not working on the first link...

Comment: Can you include the code that generates this?  Also, it looks more like a posts list than a category list.  Each link takes me to single posts and not category archives.

Comment: The category links include the list of posts:
[catlist id=3 catlink=yes numberposts=-1]

[catlist id=11 catlink=yes numberposts=-1]

[catlist id=6 catlink=yes numberposts=-1]

[catlist id=5 catlink=yes numberposts=-1]

[catlist id=4 catlink=yes numberposts=-1]

Comment: This is just the shortcode for the code.  Do you have the code for the shortcode that creates the actual lists from the  [catlist]?

Comment: This is from a plugin - "List Category Posts" there are 6 .php files associated with it. The author requested bug / problem reports through this website...

Comment: And.... theres your answer.

Comment: What answer? I think it's your answer to why the question did not make sense. yet my request to the original plugin author remains unanswered

Comment: No, it is your answer of go ask the plugin author.  If you're going to ask for help using a plugin here, you can at least post the shortcode function to it.  Without that I cannot do anything for you.  So, go ask the plugin author, and THAT is your answer.

Comment: Wow you just don't get it. The method that the author says to use to get answer is to post here an HE will answer. This is how you contact him on issues. Get it? He wants us to post here. So please, i know you originally set out to help but try to understand this is how the author wants us to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first link was displaying incorrectly because of a bug with a " sign. On line 60 of ListCatDisplayer.php, there was a wrong ":

```
$this->lcp_output .= '<' . $tag;
        if (isset($this->params['class'])): $this->lcp_output .= ' class="' . $this->params['class']; endif;
        $this->lcp_output .= '">';
```

As you can see, I was always adding the " when closing the tag. So this produced:
[image]
And if you specified a class and added more parameters, the wrong " made the whole markup to be wrong.

I've fixed it to add the " only on the class line:

```
$this->lcp_output .= '<' . $tag;
        if (isset($this->params['class'])): $this->lcp_output .= ' class="' . $this->params['class'] . '"'; endif;
        $this->lcp_output .= '>';
```

It was fixed in version 0.20.2, now ready for update. Sorry for the inconvenience, and sorry you didn't get much help in the comments. Usually users tend to be friendlier over here.

Comment: TYVM, you are awesome Fernando